# Rake seed without validations failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rake

I'm trying to populate my database with seed data using `rake db:seed` but for some reason I keep getting this error. Note, I need to bypass validations checks.

```
01_user.rb
user = User.new([
  {id: 6, email: "admin@example.com"},
  {id: 7, email: "superadmin@example.com"}
])

user.save!(validate: false)
```

Error that I keep getting:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=test
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

Any guidance on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an array of hashes to the `new` method of `User` model. You need to loop on each of these hashes instead:

```
[
  {id: 6, email: "admin@example.com"},
  {id: 7, email: "superadmin@example.com"}
].each do |user_attributes|
  user = User.new(user_attributes)
  user.save!(validate: false)
end
```

I don't think you can overwrite the `id` attribute though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
email_list = ["admin@example.com", "superadmin@example.com"]

email_list.each do |email_address|
  User.create( email: email_address )
end
```